# VBA - Most efficient method of filtering collection/dictionary of user defined classes by attribute

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, collections

My question is about filtering vba collection or dictionaries based on a property field.  I'm using VBA to process a bunch of data extracts, and have a series of custom defined class objects for that purpose.  Once I've defined them and populated them into a collection or dictionary, I need to select a subset of those objects based on various attributes.  My question is, is there a more efficient method of doing this than simply looping through and testing the condition?

Below is some basic code to illustrate the problem.  I cannot upload even an example Excel file due to my workplace policies, but the data isn't really relevant.  My test file is just a bunch of randbetween functions such as '=choose(randbetween(1,3),"red","green","blue")

```
'Simple Class definition
Option Explicit
'very simple test class
'One field is unique, the other three are simple strings that 
'fall into    groups (I don't always know what the groups will bee)

Private m_uniqueID As String
Private m_strTest1 As String
Private m_strTest2 As String
Private m_strTest3 As String

Public Property Get uniqueID() As String: uniqueID = m_uniqueID: End Property
Public Property Let uniqueID(ByVal NewValue As String): m_uniqueID = NewValue: End Property
Public Property Get strTest1() As String: strTest1 = m_strTest1: End Property
Public Property Let strTest1(ByVal NewValue As String): m_strTest1 = NewValue: End Property
Public Property Get strTest2() As String: strTest2 = m_strTest2: End Property
Public Property Let strTest2(ByVal NewValue As String): m_strTest2 = NewValue: End Property
Public Property Get strTest3() As String: strTest3 = m_strTest3: End Property
Public Property Let strTest3(ByVal NewValue As String): m_strTest3 =   NewValue: End Property
```

And my baseline approach to filtering:

```
Public Sub inefficientFilter()
    Dim oTest As cl_Test
    Dim colTest As Collection
    'assume it's populated

    Dim colMatches As Collection
    Set colMatches = New Collection

    For Each oTest In colTest
        If oTest.strTest1 = "Green" Then
            colMatches.Add Item:=oTest, Key:=oTest.uniqueID
        End If
    Next oTest
End Sub
```

This works fine, it's just that the execution time grows rather rapidly (now up to 17 seconds for 100,000 rows).  I've tried to search for an approach to this for a while, and I find a lot of references to filtering the source tables.  However, that's not practical for my data sets, as the data is heavily processed post read-in, and some of the attributes I need to filter on are not defined in the inputs.  And also, I will need to filter it on a number of different attributes, and some of those I won't know beforehand (by which I mean I know a field will contain categories, but I don't know what those categories are until the data is processed, and they may change with the next data set).

If there isn't an approach to filtering dictionaries or collections that selects more efficiently than a loop, than I was planning on either creating one large filter function that created a collection for each categorical field, so that I could at least avoid looping each time I need to apply a filter and handle it all in one go.  Or alternatively, to write out something of a hashtable to a single excel sheet, and us adodb.recordset queries to find matches (I haven't tested that enough to know which has less overhead).  However, before I went there, I thought I'd ask if I was missing something obvious.

Thanks!

-added 12/15

Mat Mug's first comment mentions iterating over the keys array of a dictionary, and suggested using a for...next loop instead.  So I went and modified my code to test the time of different methods of iterating.  I thought I should share the results.  I tested 7 methods, and also Tim William's answer below.  I figured it was okay to just summarize this without fully detailing the code, since it was pretty trivial.  If I'm wrong, I can easily add it. I ran this on 10,000 items (because two methods caused my computer to commit suicide if I went to 300k).  So here're the results, with the duration in seconds of the time to complete the loop (each loop iterates through the collection or dictionary, and then tests the each item for a given condition, and if match then add that item to a results collection):

1. 0.00578 For each Loop, looping through the collection (for each o in col)
2. 0.20099 For Next Loop, using a counter as an index to the collection, and
   then retrieving an item through SET obj = col(i)
3. 0.27605 For Next Loop, same as 2 but skipping the SET.
   so test condition was if col(i).strtest1 = "Green" then ...)
4. 0.01275 Dictionaries now.  For each key in dict.keys, SET obj = dict(key)
5. 0.02605 For each key in dict 
   excluding SET, so as with 3, 
   test condition was dict(key).strtest1 = "Green" then ...)
6. 3.68905 For Next with an index, for i = 1 to dict.count, set o = dict(i)
7. 4.16361 Same as 6 but without the SET 
   dict.items(i).strTest1 = "Green" then...
8. 0.02192 And also Tim William's answer below

So from this I learn never, ever iterate over a dictionary with an index. 
Also, VBA is much faster when dealing directly with objects (using SET) than accessing via a reference to a collection or dictionary.
The fastest method is a simple FOR EACH obj IN Collection, NEXT obj loop.  Simply iterating through a dictionary (FOR EACH key IN dict.keys, SET obj = dict(key), NEXT key) takes a bit over twice as long (which makes sense, as there's an extra operation on each loop, the SET function).  Though the tax of this would be fixed per loop, so if you're doing more than one operation during the loop (testing more than one condition), this would become less significant.  And Mr. William's method is comparable to the for each key method.

Okay, given that I just re-ran the test iterating the match function (emulating a situation in which I'm not just filtering, but processing the filtered selection).  So in case my headers fail, this is supposed to read as Method Number, Elapsed time for Method to complete 1 match operation, Factor of how much longer each method takes than the fastest method for 1 match, elapsed time for method to complete 50 match operations, factor of how much longer that was than baseline.

Method__1x(s)**Factor(1x)__50x(s)_____Factor(50x)
1_______0.006____1_________0.159_______1__loop for each on collection
2_______0.201___35_________0.336_______2__for next with an index
3_______0.276___48________19.165_____120**#2 skipping SET
4_______0.013____2_________0.159_______1__for each key in dict
5_______0.026____5_________5.560______35__#4 skipping SET
6_______3.689__369_________3.851______24__for next on dict with index
7_______4.164__721_______211.929____1333__#6 skipping SET
8_______0.022____4_________0.144_______1__Mr. William's answer

So this reinforces the answer form above.  A for-each loop on an equation, or a for each key in dict.keys, set obj=dict(key), and Mr. William's answer are all similarly efficient as the complexity grows.  The impact of using an index decreases with the number of times you access a property, but it's less efficient than using the for each approach.  And finally, VBA is much more efficient when you directly access a class object, as opposed to accessing it by reference from a parent collection/dictionary.  Maybe this is obvious to everyone but me, as I don't have a programming background and am learning as I go, but it's nice to put some quantification to my intuition and rules of thumb.

I realize I'm blurring into 3 different questions at this point.  The fastest way to filter, the fastest way to iterate, and the fastest way to access a property of an object in a collection or dictionary.  Sorry if this is too far afield, I just wanted to share what I was learning from reading through your answers.

Comment: You could populate a disconnected ADO recordset while you're building your objects and use its `Filter` and/or `Sort` methods to find and/or order matches.  https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3846361/Create-In-Memory-ADO-Recordsets.htm   If your objects are in a dictionary keyed on the unique id then you can use the recordset an an "index" to the objects themselves.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't meant to be iterated. Also your title says "sorting" but your entire post says "filtering" - the two are completely different things. Whatever you do, you'll need O(n) operations, where n is the number of items in your collection. Unless you can ensure that the items are already sorted by some key field, and then you can stop iterating once that key field starts being different. Have you tried `For...Next` on arrays? Dictionary keys are an array. `For Each` on arrays is very slow.

Comment: How are you populating the collection? By reading from a `Range` of cells? You could use autofilters to set your criteria *before* you even start populating the collection, and the problem solves itself.

Comment: To Mat's second question - yes the data does come from Ranges, and so pre filtering is possible for some cases (some require a lot of post- processing logic).  However, the number of permutations that I'm being asked to report-out keeps growing.  As such, I'd have to re-query/filter a large number of times.  And since there is definitely post-processing required prior to writing out the reports, I'd be repeatedly reading the same rows into a data structure.  Are the build in auto-filters so much quicker than looping through collections that such an approach could be more efficient?

Answer (score 3):

Tested with 300k objects using your example class.

**EDIT**: updated with a little more filtering flexibility.

```
Dim data As Object

Sub Tester()

    Dim colF As Collection
    Dim arr, o As Class1, n As Long, t, k, o2 As Variant

    arr = Array("Red", "Green", "Blue")
    Set data = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'load up some test data
    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To 300000#
        Set o = New Class1
        o.uniqueID = "ID" & Format(n, "000000000")
        o.strTest1 = arr(Int((2 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0))
        o.strTest2 = arr(Int((2 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0))
        o.strTest3 = arr(Int((2 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0))
        data.Add o.uniqueID, o
    Next n
    Debug.Print "Loaded", Timer - t

    'do some filtering
    t = Timer
    Debug.Print "filtered", Filtered("strTest1", "Red").Count, Timer - t
    t = Timer
    Debug.Print "filtered", Filtered("strTest2", "Green").Count, Timer - t
    t = Timer
    Debug.Print "filtered", Filtered("strTest3", "Blue").Count, Timer - t

End Sub

'generic filtering on named property+value
Function Filtered(propName As String, propValue As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, o As Variant
    For Each o In data.items
        If CallByName(o, propName, VbGet) = propValue Then rv.Add o.uniqueID
    Next o
    Set Filtered = rv
End Function
```

Output:

```
Loaded                       6.601563 
filtered       100006        0.7109375 
filtered       99936         0.828125 
filtered       100144        0.9609375
```

Creating the objects is the slow part: filtering is pretty fast.

If your real class is just a collection of fields then you *might* get better performance using a custom Type instead of a class.  Either way, if you're still having issues it would be best to update your question to include a fully-worked out example of the type of thing you need to work quickly.

Comment: FYI: I referenced your post in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to create a Dictionary of Dictionaries to manage the Objects.  After the initial instantiation there would be little overhead in retrieving the Objects.

This method took about 50% longer to load then @TimWilliams example but the Objects were Indexed based on the value of each of their 4 properties not just the 1 property in Tim's demonstration.

### Class: clTest_Collection

```
Public dictAll As Object
Public dicStr1 As Object
Public dicStr2 As Object
Public dicStr3 As Object

Public Sub Add(uniqueID As String, str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String)
    Dim obj As cl_Test
    Set obj = New cl_Test
    With obj
        .uniqueID = uniqueID
        .strTest1 = str1
        .strTest2 = str1
        .strTest3 = str1
    End With

    dictAll.Add obj.uniqueID, obj
    AddToDictionary dicStr1, obj, str1
    AddToDictionary dicStr2, obj, str2
    AddToDictionary dicStr3, obj, str3

End Sub

Private Sub AddToDictionary(ByRef dict As Object, ByRef obj As cl_Test, ByRef value As String)
    If Not dict.Exists(value) Then dict.Add value, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict(value).Add obj.uniqueID, obj
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set dictAll = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dicStr1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dicStr2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dicStr3 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
```

### Module1: Public Module

```
Sub Test()
    Dim t As Single, x As Long
    Dim ObjCollection As clTest_Collection
    Set ObjCollection = New clTest_Collection

    t = Timer
    For x = 1 To 300000
        ObjCollection.Add "Item" & x, getRndColor, getRndColor, getRndColor
    Next
     Debug.Print "Total Time in Seconds: "; Timer - t
End Sub

Function getRndColor() As String
    getRndColor = Choose(Int(Rnd * 3) + 1, "Red", "Green", "Blue")
End Function
```